# Remote Debug "Chrome Mobile" to "PC"

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I want to inspect and debug a Chrome Mobile application on my "chrome pc/machine", 
so I've followed [this](http:// eveloper.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging-legacy
) Google tutorial.

When I acessed localhost:9222, it lists the correct sites opened on my android chrome.
But the following error occurs when I click on "Inspectable pages". The console show the message

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@178678/178678.manifest
Application Cache Checking event

[blocked] The page at 'https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/@178678/devtools.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/0' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'ws://<localhost>:9222/devtools/page/0': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

Comment: On which computer are you accessing localhost:9222?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too.

According to this report [Chromium Issue 398817](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398817), you can add the --allow-running-insecure-content when launching Chrome.

This worked for me on Windows 7.